# Google Drive automation - server2server

Tags: php, google-drive-api

after days of searching, I have concluded that the right question would be better. I am working on app backend. I need it to backup some files regularly on Google Drive. Do I understand it correctly that I need Google For Work account so I can use Server2Server?

According to this
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts
Google wants me to grant access only via Google For Work account. Have I missed anything if I just want my web based php script executed by cron to backup few files on Google Drive? Is there any other option?

Thank you!

Comment: take the service account email address and add it as a user to the a folder on your personal Google Drive account and the service account will have access to it like any other user.

Answer (score 1):

The account that Google Drive connects to is determined by the content of your OAuth Access Token. If you'd like to do server-to-drive, where the Drive account is your own, see the instructions in [How do I authorise an app (web or installed) without user intervention? (canonical ?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-an-app-web-or-installed-without-user-intervention-canonic)